# Problem with ssh connections between two machines with Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I have two fresh installations of Ubuntu 16.04. On both `ssh -V` gives

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

When I connect from machine A (laptop) to machine B (remote), I first get connection immediately but it is always closed in a few minutes and I cannot establish connection again. `ssh` command does not write anything on the screen, just wait and nothing is going on (so it is idle and never connects). If I call `ssh -vvv username@remotemachine` I get

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "remotemachine" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.40.2.110 [10.40.2.110] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
```

Interestingly, if now I go by `ssh` to another machine and connect from it, it works (at least first time). When it connects first time, `ssh -vvv` writes after messages shown above:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to remotemachine as 'klykov'
```

I wonder which machine is not properly configured (client or server) and how I can fix this issue.

**RESULT** The issue is due to the IP conflict in the local network.

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the output of `ssh -vvv username@machine-name`

Comment: It isn't clear in your question - did you manage to `ssh` from machine `A` to `B` and login into machine `B` and after several minutes the connection is closed, or you wait for several minutes without managing to login into `B`?

Comment: Idle timeout or real disconnect ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl idle timeout

Comment: `@KirillLykov` okay, please add the "idle timeout information" to your question, I've posted an answer to the *idle timeout* problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idle timeouts are handled both on the SSH server and the client.

So you need to configure `TCPKeepAlive`, `ServerAliveInterval` in seconds on the client `ssh_config` and `ClientAliveInterval`on the server /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

uncomment or edit

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 600 # Timeout after 10 minutes, uncomment if no timeout
```

then restart service (or equivalent)

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

on the client

`nano .ssh/config`

```
Host *
TCPKeepAlive=yes
ServerAliveInterval 600      # Same logic as above
```

Comment: I tried it on both machines to be sure, doesn't work. So when I try to connect second time client hangs (with the same from ssh -vvv).

Comment: Is the `ssh -vvv` the first or second try for the connection ?

Comment: the long output of `ssh -vvv` is for the second try to connect (why it does not work). When I connect the first time, it prints the same but after that also other information (second peace is shown in the post)

Comment: and I need to add that if I wait for some time (tens of minutes) than it connects again

Comment: Do you have something installed like `fail2ban` ?

Comment: no, it is very clean installation

Comment: ..and there are no IP or DNS conflicts ? `UseDNS no` is also an idea (server side)

Comment: Hm,  true, it might be IP conflict. I guess need to ask admin of local network. Is there a way to detect out such conflicts?

Comment: Ping from both sides is a fast and easy method (depends on your infrastructure)